# Database of common packaging icons (food, CPG, GM)

Tags: food, photographs

Building a classifier that takes as input, a photo of a product and then identifies the common icons in that photo (e.g., recycle, non-GMO, kosher, fat free, gluten free, vegan, etc.). I am aware of the icons at [thenounproject.com](http://thenounproject.com), but I am looking for more variants (pictures of the icons on actual products) so that the classifier generalizes well to real-world cases.

Comment: While not pictures on the products, you may be interested in the trademark electronic search system. It’s a database that includes the icons you mentioned. http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4808:g7am2t.1.1

Answer (score 1):

[Kwikee](https://www.kwikee.com/cpg-images-data-retailers.shtml) has a free database of current product images. It’s sponsored by manufactures; and freely available to retailers.

I would ask to see if you can get access. While not a retailer, I gained an account given I had a few good reasons for making such a request.

> [Thousands of brands trust Kwikee to deliver content to retailers – and retailers rely on our free, manufacturer-approved content for their e-commerce, marketing, mobile and merchandising needs.](https://www.kwikee.com/about-kwikee.shtml)